# New SSH user with access to a specific directory

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I created a fresh LAMP stack droplet (Ubuntu 12.04) in Digital Ocean service. Now I have to provide my co-worker with access to server web directory (/var/www) via SSH/SFTP. How could it be done right way?

Comment: create a user on the system for your co-worker. Set appropriate permissions for the user to access /var/www. Ensure that SSH service is up (most likely is by default). Any user on the system can connect via SSH so long as SSH is up.

Comment: @MaQleod Could you please describe how to set these permissions? New user should be able to see only `/var/www` with subdirectories not root folders like `/bin`, `/etc` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a user for your co-worker using [`useradd`](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/add-a-user-on-ubuntu-server/). If only your co-worker needs access, you can then run `sudo chown -R co-worker /var/www` where you replace `co-worker` with the corresponding username.

If you need to give multiple people access to the directory, [create a group](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man8/groupadd.8.html) and add everybody there. Run `sudo chgrp -R groupname /var/www`.

Make sure the SSH server is installed and running.

Comment: I tried this. Unfortunately, `co-worker` can see all root directories not only `/var/www`.

Comment: That's normal. If you wanted higher security, you should've mentioned this in your question. The common way to do this, is by using a jail. I found this article about it: http://allanfeid.com/content/creating-chroot-jail-ssh-access. However, you may be better off setting up an FTP server in your case: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html. Just know that `/bin`, `/etc` are nothing scary for other users to read.